# Don't show Vaadin messages during TestBench test run (@PreserveOnRefresh, reload)

Tags: vaadin-testbench

How can I get rid of the dismiss messages displayed during a Vaadin TestBench test run in the right lower corner? Clicking by human does not help. Messages will appear on next test run.

image: [dismiss messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7WQ5.png)

- @PreserveOnRefresh enabled
- Java live reload unavailable

Vaadin 23

Comment: Did you try clicking on "Don't show again"?

Comment: Clicking does not help. The messages appear on the next test run again. I guess I have to click them using Selenium Shadow DOM (how?) or change something in the Vaadin code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run tests in Production Mode by setting `vaadin.productionMode` to `true`. This will disable the developer mode widget. If you're using Maven, you might have a separate profile for this purpose, such as

```
<profile>
    <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
    <id>production</id>
    <properties>
        <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
    </properties>
    <!-- ... -->
```

With Gradle, put

```
vaadin {
   productionMode = true
}
```

in your build.gradle file.

Comment: I use Eclipse 22-3 and Gradle 7.4 and have problems to set this option.

Comment: I can not use the production mode because then all IDs are gone. (We publish IDs only in development mode.) Is there a possibility to get rid of the dismiss messages?

Comment: You're misusing production mode. Maybe you should use something else to make the decision to add/remove ids, such as an environment property (with Spring, this is super easy with application.properties)

Comment: added Gradle instructions.